# HTACCESS, not on a certain page

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes

I would like to check if a user enters a website via one of the following urls

```
(en|nl|fr|de|es|pl|sv|it|cs|el|fi|hu)/(home|business|product|contact|faq|gallery|videos|locator)
```

else, i would like to redirect the user to the 404 page.

i've tried this:

```
RewriteRule !^((en|nl|fr|de|es|pl|sv|it|cs|el|fi|hu)/(home|business|product|contact|faq|gallery|videos|locator)|404)$ /404 [L,R=307]
```

but this gives me a routing loop.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^404|(?:css|js|jpg|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^(en|nl|fr|de|es|pl|sv|it|cs|el|fi|hu)/(home|business|product|contact|faq|gallery|videos|locator) - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: this seems to work. However, now, all of my images/css/scripts are not loaded correctly, they are situated in the /uploads directory.

Comment: I added a condition so we don't 404 files ending in `css` etc. You know how to add extensions if needed. Let me know if this works. :) Btw if you still get a 404, try a different browser as your browser may have cached the 404—or clear the cache.

Comment: oh, one last thing, i have a custom 404 page. that's why i routed to /404 in the first place. however, i get an infinite loop, because the 404 page is not in the exceptions. sorry to bother you, htaccess is all very, very new to me :)

Comment: +1 for continuous support to help the OP. @ThomasdeRoo: It always helps if you post your full .htaccess in question.